# some rows are missing on results of my query

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to get report between 2 dates with PersianCalendar and I've already converted the dates. It does not show me the data about last day
This is my code:

```
   public ActionResult FilterDate(DateFormViewModel model)
    {
        PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();
        var dateFrom = pc.ToDateTime(model.FromYear, model.FromMonth, model.FromDay, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        var dateTo = pc.ToDateTime(model.ToYear, model.ToMonth, model.ToDay, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        var filter = db.Parts.Where(s => s.CreateDateTime >= dateFrom && s.CreateDateTime <= dateTo).ToList();
        return View("Index", filter);
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing data on the last day, right? (15 mordad)
The reason is that you are looking to the same day. having <= in the query does not help you. 
for instance 1395/5/15 01:00:00 is greater than 1395/5/15 (your dateTo) and therefore it will not show up in the results

you have to check it with next day

```
  var filter = db.Parts.Where(s => s.CreateDateTime >= dateFrom && s.CreateDateTime < dateTo.AddDay(1)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks both of answer is true.thank you for edit

Comment: Your welcome @Joewalter, you can also vote up for both answers

Comment: I can not because I was careless and negative rating was in question.

Comment: I'll vote for ejoshuas then ;)

Comment: If possible give a positive rating to my question

Answer (score 2):

You're searching from midnight of the start date to 12 AM of the end date. You want to search from midnight of the start date to 11:59:59 PM of the end date.

Comment: thanks this right it,s work thank you!!!